# How to Checkbox validation on frontend?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document )
    .ready( function () {
        $( '#btnStatus' )
            .click( function () {
                var isChecked = $( '#chkSelect' )
                    .attr( 'checked' );
                alert( isChecked );
            } );
    } );
</script>
<button type="submit" id="btnStatus" class="btn btn-secondary" name="signup">Sign Up</button>
```

But i want if not submit just validate how ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you right.. but have you tried with event.preventDefault();

Comment: Change the button's type from submit to button

Answer (score 1):

```
return false;
```

Complete code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#btnStatus').click(function(){
  var isChecked = $('#chkSelect').attr('checked');
  alert(isChecked);
  return false;
});
});
</script>
<button type="submit" id="btnStatus" class="btn btn-secondary" name="signup">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: wehn select same pop how to prevent when select

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

`$("#checkboxId").is(":checked");` this returns you with true or false. If it is checked, it returns true, else false.

Know more about it from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_is.asp).

As per your script, it should be like

```
$("#btnStatus").click(function() {
var isChecked = $("#chkSelect").is(":checked");
alert(isChecked);
});
```